# QString, Parse and replace some specific sections

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qstring

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
QString str = "23+34-343+$T$-3+$OPC$";
```

I want to replace every sections which are enclosed by two $ will be replaced with %0, %1 and so on. 
So the above example would be : "23+34-343+%0-3+%1"

I can detect the sections by using QRegularExpression and with this pattern: "\$.+?\$"

What is the best and most optimized way (not to use loops and indices) to replace those sections with %0, %1, %2  and so on.

Comment: Note that I cant use QString::replace since the string in which is aimed to replace with $x$ is not constant.

Comment: You can split the string using `QStringList list = str.split(QRegExp("\\$[^$]+\\$"));`  and then loop through the items and join them with incrementing numbers.

Comment: You can also use `QString::section()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this:

```
QString str = "23+34-343+$T$-3+$OPC$";

QRegExp rx;
rx.setMinimal(true);
rx.setPattern("\\$.+\\$");
str.replace(rx, "X");           //First replace every pattern with something like 'X'

for(int i=0 ;str.indexOf("X")!=-1; i++)
    str.replace(str.indexOf("X"), 1,"%"+QString::number(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

I realy can't understand why you don't want to use loops. I think it is very effective way in your case.

I write some example, but do not claim authorship the best solution:

```
QString str = "23+34-343+$T$-3+$OPC$";

int pos = 0, nextPos = 0, iterationNumber = 0;
while ((pos = str.indexOf("$")) > 0 && (nextPos = str.indexOf("$", pos + 1)) > 0)
    str.replace(pos, nextPos - pos + 1, "%" + QString::number(iterationNumber++));
```